# How to make redux not update every time when change page with tab navigation in react native

Tags: react-native, redux

First of all, I don't know about redux well. So, I'm sorry for insufficient information.

I make a app by react-native and django and use redux.
I also use tab navigation with four tabs, and these tabs get items by redux.

I'm just wondering when I test app and move through tabs, the redux request to server every time.

In this situation, I want to make the app just give request when enter the page for the first time or user (who use this app) requested or the data was changed, not every time.

Can you give me some tips about this situation? Abstract and simple tips are fine.
I'm sorry again about giving insufficient information.

Comment: The routing in your application shouldn't cause a reload in the application. It should only give a feel or switching "pages" but still stay a SPA. With this in mind if you have setup the routing correctly, maybe components from different tabs are asking for the same information though requests. What you could do is check your redux store before executing the request. If the information is already in the store, don't send a request to the backend.

Comment: Thanks for answer me! I didn't know about SPA... I will check about your answer and change it. Thanks again.